# Is a set of points equally distant from one point (sphere) equidistant?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

What is the mathematical definition of *equidistant* ?

[Here](http://easycalculation.com/maths-dictionary/equidistant.html) I found:

> If the distance of each object of a set of objects to the point is same, then the point is called equidistant.

The term is usually used in cases where "the set of objects" refers to more than one object. **Can it be used also in case of one object only?** Or is there another term for that? I am especially interested in the case of one point in 3 dimensional space (sphere).

Comment: Well if you compare one point to a single point only, then *equidistant* doesn't really apply. equidistant ("equally distant") is a comparison, and you can't compare a single thing (to what would you compare it to?)

Comment: If you want to compare your point to a sphere, then your point would be equidistant to *the set of points* in your sphere.

Comment: @Lisa Good point, I guess, I was getting the idea of equidistant somehow wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a single point $p$ in a metric space $(M,d)$, you can definitely define a set of points $S$ such that $d(s,p)=d(s',p)$ for all $(s,s')\in S\times S$. One might call $S$ a segment of the *sphere of radius $d(s,p)$* centered at $p$.

In this case $p$ has the property that it is equidistant to the set $S$ (although there may be other points with this property in some metric spaces, or even in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $S$ has cardinality $n$ or less).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So the answer on my question is: NO, it is just to opposite.

Answer (score 0):

"equidistant: a point the same distance from two or more other points." So for example, the discrete metric satisfies this.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/b/f/1bfabe2211af146e4d250eeb9f921080.png